# Passing value from Google Login to JSF login

Tags: javascript, java, jsf-2, glassfish, google-authentication

I'm kinda new to all of this, but I have a JSF Web Application (which works) which also has a Google Authentication (google authentication works by itself);

I'm trying to pass the response from the google Auth to the JSF login (the email address & google Id) which will then authenticate via a JdbcRealm;

So just to clarify, the JSF authentication via a JdbcRealm works by itself, and the google login by itself works - i just want to pass the response from google (of the email address & google id) to be used as the JSF authentication, & automate the click action of the JSF auth form.

My issue is, that after i log into google, i get the error

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Here's my JSF login page with all the Javascript;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <meta name="description" content="NDIS Management System"/>
        <meta name="author" content="Danielle Walker"/>
        <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="270287108664-3g7l6e6ah3gr5am9onokua84t3bvdbvf.apps.googleusercontent.com" />

        <title>NDIS Home</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <h:outputStylesheet name="bootstrap/css/the-big-picture.css"  />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/google-button.css" />
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <f:verbatim>
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->    
        </f:verbatim>

        <!-- Google API Javascript needs to be loaded in the page before the actual Javascript -->
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js" />

        <ui:insert name="head"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body class="full">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-right">
                        <li>
                            <div id="gSignInWrapper" style="padding-top:5px;">
                                <div id="customBtn" class="customGPlusSignIn" style="float: right;">
                                    <span class="icon"></span><span class="buttonText">Sign In</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span style="color:#f9f9f9"><div id="name"></div></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>

        <h:form id="login" onsubmit="document.getElementById('login').action = 'j_security_check';" prependId="false">
            <!--<h:panelGrid columns="2">-->
            <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
            <h:inputText id="j_username" />            
            <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
            <h:inputText id="j_password" size="8"/>
            <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Login" />
            <!--</h:panelGrid>-->
        </h:form>

        <f:verbatim>
            <script>
                var googleUser = {};
                var startApp = function () {
                    gapi.load('auth2', function () {
                        // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
                        auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                            client_id: '270287108664-3g7l6e6ah3gr5am9onokua84t3bvdbvf.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                            cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin'
                                    // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                                    //scope: 'additional_scope'
                        });
                        attachSignin(document.getElementById('customBtn'));
                    });
                };
            </script>
        </f:verbatim>

        <script>startApp();</script>
        <f:verbatim>
            <script>
                function attachSignin(element) {
                    console.log(element.id);
                    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
                            function (googleUser) {
                                //document.getElementById('name').text = "Signed in: " +
                                //        googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId();
                                document.getElementById("login.j_username").value = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
                                document.getElementById("login.j_password").value = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getId();
                            }, function (error) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
                        //alert("Opps... an error Occured");
                    });
                }
                function signOut() {
                    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                        console.log('User signed out.');
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </f:verbatim>
        <ui:insert name="body"/>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
        <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <h:outputScript name="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
        <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js" />

    </h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my own problem;

With my error message, the problem was obviously in the way i was trying to access the "j_username" & "j_password elements:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Anyway, by changing the code i had:

```
document.getElementById("login.j_username").value = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
```

To instead look like this:

```
document.getElementById("login").elements[1].value = googleUser.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
```

In short, the problem was the way i was trying to address the elements of the form, and by addressing the form itself, and then the elements of the form (being in a 0 based array), then it works